# Build cefclient with boost

Tags: c++, windows, boost, chromium-embedded

I have CEF working solution. I try add some functionality to *cefclient* project. If I include any boost libraries I have `LNK1104` error (for ex. `LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_66`').

Project with boost need `/MD` but *cefclient* builded with `/MT`. I don't know what parameters setup boost working with `/MT`. Can you tell me how I can build boost binaries for `/MT`?

> Windows 10 x64
>
> VS2017
>
> CEF x32

For me not matter use /MD or /MT, I want use both cef and boost in one project. If is other way to do that please let me know.

Comment: You cannot mix, your client needs to use /MD as well.

Comment: I saw boost building for /MT but for osx. I understand nothing with boost building and hope anyone help me with it for win10